# Calling function from form when "enter" by a prototype

Tags: javascript, forms, prototype, keyboard-events

I'm trying to create a method for a form Element that allow to define a function will be called when "enter" key is pressed and the form is focused. Here is a testing code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Teste Form Enter</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
Element.prototype.addEnterEvent = function(Func){
    var me = this;
    this.gotFocus = false;
    this.addEventListener("focus", function(){ me.gotFocus = true; }, false);
    this.addEventListener("focusOut", function() { me.gotFocus = false; }, false);
    window.addEventListener("keyPress", function(e) { console.log("Hit!"); if(me.gotFocus && e.which==13) window[Func](); }, false);
}

function formHandler(){
    alert("Anything: "+document.forms["test"].anything.value);
}

function ini(){
    document.getElementById("test").addEnterEvent(formHandler);
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="ini();">
<form name="test" id="test" onsubmit="return false;">
    <label>Anything: </label>
    <input type="text" name="anything" />
    <br />
    <button onclick="formHandler();" type="button">Hit Enter</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The purpose is if enter is hit, the same function will be called if button is pressed.
There is no error message, neither the desired result, just nothing happens. I put the console.log and the key event is not firing - so nothing happens. Why?

EDIT: Trying to use the suggestion, should work, but the form is send after run the formHandler, and I don't want this happens:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function formHandler(formElement){
    alert("Anything: "+formElement.elements.anything.value);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="#" name="test" id="test" onsubmit="formHandler(); return false;" method="get">
    <label>Anything: </label>
    <input type="text" name="anything" />
    <br />
    <button onclick="formHandler();" type="submit">Hit Enter</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to do this. If a `<form>` tag has an `action` attribute and at least one submit button, then you can use the onsubmit:

```
<form action="#" method="GET" onsubmit="formHandler(event, this); return false;">
    <input type="text" name="foo">
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Note that `<button type="button" />` will not work. It must be `<button type="submit" />` or `<input type="submit|image" />`

**EDIT:** Changed the formHandler method a little so the `form` gets passed in as an argument. Also see the slight change to the `onsubmit` attribute, passing `this` into the formHandler function.

```
function formHandler(event, form) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(form.elements.foo.value);
}
```

**Edit:** Changed the code in my answer to pass the `event` object into the handler and call `preventDefault()`.

Comment: It works too much! It runs the script formHandler but send the form, witch is undesired. In the tests I've made, if there is a submit button, the form is send, event with return false inside onsubmit. In theory should work, I think, but not in real life. But is a good point to explore here.

Comment: You'll need to pass the `event` object into the handler function, then call `event.preventDefault()` to keep the form from submitting.

Comment: Yes, preventDefault will do the job! However, I did a code with addEventListener. Do you want to complete your answer so I can mark it or should I answer my own question?

Comment: Thanks! I'd put some extra code below, for those want to follow from here to more complex applications.

Answer (score 0):

Greg answered the question, but this is an alternate way to do the same:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Teste Form Enter</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function formHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target.elements.anything.value);
    alert("Anything: "+e.target.elements.anything.value);
}
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        console.log("initialized...");
        document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("submit", formHandler, true);
    }, false);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="#" name="test" id="test" method="get">
    <label>Anything: </label>
    <input type="text" name="anything" />
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Hit Enter</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And if you don't use form, or want to try by prototype, here is a start:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Teste Form Enter</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
Element.prototype.addEnterEvent = function(Func){
    var me = this;
    this.Func = Func;
    this.gotFocus = false;
    this.addEventListener("focus", function(){ me.gotFocus = true; }, false);
    this.addEventListener("blur", function(){ me.gotFocus = false; }, false);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) { 
            if(me.gotFocus && e.which==13) {
                Func();
            }
        }, false);
}

function enterHandler(){
    alert("Anything: "+document.getElementById("anything").value);
}

function ini(){
    document.getElementById("anything").addEnterEvent(enterHandler);
    //window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){ console.log("Key: "+e.which); }, false);
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="ini();">
    <h1>OnEnter Test</h1>
    <label>Anything: </label>
    <input type="text" name="anything" id="anything" />
    <br />
    <button onclick="enterHandler();" type="button">Hit Enter</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If you're doing a login in Ajax, you can add to the last text box (pass or captcha) so when the user hit enter, the login function will be called.